# Wordpress filter relationship by post types

Tags: wordpress

I have two custom Post Types I'have created with Toolset plugin: `sponsor` and `book`.

I have created a relationship (with Toolset) beetween those two post types: a sponsor could have 1 or more books (slug for relationship is `sponsor-book`).

**IMPORTANT:** a book could not have a sponsor as parent.

**What I need is to get all sponsors and all books without sponsor.**

This is what I do (books with sponsor are included, I don't want to):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('sponsor', 'book')
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

How can I exclude the books that have a sponsor?

Comment: Is it too late to change a plugin? I'd rather us CPTUI than toolset and use acf for relationship. You can easily manipulate these inside the $args.

Comment: Yeah it's too late at the time

Answer (score 1):

Try this. First I took the object of sponsor and book post type. By getting the IDs of both post type I check them if has toolset parent the insert them inside the filtered array. Then print the post title of those filtered array.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('sponsor', 'book')
);
$both_posts = get_posts( $args );

$arr = array();
$num= 0;
if( $both_posts ): 

  foreach( $both_posts as $k => $both_post ): 

    $posts_without_sponsor_id = toolset_get_related_post( 
        $both_post->ID,
        'sponsor-book', //slug of relationship
        'parent'
    );

    if( !$posts_without_sponsor_id ):
        $arr['filteredposts'][$num] = $event->ID;
        $num++;
    endif;

   endforeach;

 endif;

// Filtered IDs
if($arr['filteredposts']): 
foreach( $arr['filteredposts'] as $filtered ):
    echo $filtered->post_title;
endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: This was my first solution: filter results after get_posts. In this way I get all posts in query, it's not good. I'm looking for something to pass to get_posts in $args.